# Show English tabs regardless of current site language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

A localised Drupal 7 site has four languages. Three non-English languages are for the site content, and English is the admin language. Most users won't be logged in. The only logged-in users will be admin or editors.

For logged-in users, the View/Edit/Translate/Devel tabs (`$tabs` in page.tpl.php) are shown in the current site language. But as these are only intended for admin, it makes more sense to show these in the admin language (English).

How can I always show the tabs in English (or the admin language)?

(One workaround is to remove the translations for the strings in the tabs, but that would have to be repeated if any new tabs or languages are added.)

Comment: Just dont provide translation for the tabs text :D

Comment: @NikhilM: Yes, I mentioned that as a workaround in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just used the workaround: removed the translations for the strings in the tabs. There weren't too many.